# How to check number of load time of a page in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my scenario I,ve three pages in which one page load another page after 5 second duration, Now i want that when all the three pages loaded 200 time i want to stop loading of the pages further how can i achieve this using javasvript following is my code.

page1.html

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Page1</title>
  </head>

<body>
<h1>Hello, This is page 1.</h1>
<div id="redirect" style="color: red;"></div>
    <p>page 1</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Redirect() 
{  

    window.location="page2.html"; 

} 

document.getElementById('redirect').innerHTML= " wait... You will be redirected to page 2 within 5 second" 
     setInterval('Redirect()', 5000); 
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Page2.html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page2</title>
 </head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, This is page 2</h1>
  <div id="redirect" style="color:red;"></div>
    <p>page 2</p>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function Redirect() 
     {  
          window.location="page3.html"; 
     } 
 document.getElementById('redirect').innerHTML= "wait... You will be redirected page3 withing 5 seconds"; 
         setInterval('Redirect()',5000); 
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

page3.html

```
 <html>
   <head>
   <title>Page3</title>
   </head>

     <body>
      <h1>Hi This is page 3.</h1>
       <div id="redirect" style="color:red;"></div>
      <p>page 3</p>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function Redirect() 
      {  
        window.location="page1.html"; 
      } 
      document.getElementById('redirect').innerHTML = "You will be redirected to page 1 within 5 second."; 
setInterval('Redirect()', 5000); 
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `...when all three pages loaded 200 times...`  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to stop page loading further

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your end goal is but I bet you can keep track of the number of times each page loads by setting some sort of cookie var or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) in each page.

for example...

```
// Do this for each page. (add to bottom of each page, renaming the sessionStorage names for each).

// See if we have a pageLoadedCount value
if (sessionStorage.getItem("pageLoadedCount")) {
  var addPageLoadCount = sessionStorage.getItem("pageLoadedCount") + 1;
  sessionStorage.setItem("pageLoadedCount", addPageLoadCount);
}else{
  sessionStorage.setItem("pageLoadedCount", 1);
}
```

Comment: This work if convert to integer like parseInt( sessionStorage.getItem("pageLoadedCount") )+ 1

Answer (score 0):

You should use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the count of loads.

On each page load you can check whether the load count has reached 200 or not.

If it has prevent the current page from reloading and set the load count to 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $(window).load(function(){}) to set variable in local storage and check  it every time window load